# Windows hangs on first boot ... mostly

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I having some strange problems with the windows 7 PC of my mother in law.

Mostly every time she starts her PC "after a while" (time is not really specifiable - often about a day) Windows hang up on boot. Windows don't really hang up, but you can see background image and cursor (is movable - so no real freeze) and that's all. No explorer, icons or else what. Taskmanager is not startable. She can wait hours but nothing happened.

After hardreset (hardware button) mostly (sometimes she has to try it up to 5 times until windows runs) windows starts without any problems and runs stable. Now you can shutdown or restart - Windows will not freeze. But if she try it for example next day: mostly same problem a above mentioned.

Long time test of hardware form a pc company are without fails.

Considering the specificity problem and against the hardware test I am not sure if this is really a windows problem, because of the pc has this problem since beginning, but failure frequency increases.

Anyone with a idea how to narrowing the problem?

Comment: Well I would start with a fresh installation if the problem happens after that the. It's a hardware problem

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes yes, I know :-/ - this question is more or less the last try to avoid this, because this is a lot of work to bring "this" pc back to the current point.

Comment: Is this before login or after it? What does Ctrl-Alt-Del do? Is there hard drive activity led - does it burn constantly?

Comment: @kohtala: it is auto-login, but I tend to say "before"; Ctrl-Alt-Del has no effect; led shows some activity and than turns off - if you look only on the led it seam like a normal - but slow - boot.

Comment: I suggest you start deactivating stuff that runs at startup one by one until you get the culprit. I once had a semi-responsive system that was being hung up by Messenger not starting up correctly.

Comment: Try booting in safe mode. If it works, disable auto-login to see if it is before login or during. See what is in the system event log.